# Получение значения Toggle Switch из Settings Bundle

Tags: xcode, ios, objective-c, settings

Как я понял после рытья доков в сети, значения установленные в `Settings Bundle` можно получить через  [`NSUserDefaults standartDefaults`].

Каков синтаксис обращения к значению на примере `Toggle Switch`?

P.S.

Нашел что ключ достается следующим образом:

```
NSUserDefaults *defaults = [NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults];
toggleSwitchValue = [defaults objectForKey:@"PSToggleSwitchSpecifier"];
```

в таком варианте `toggleSwitchValue` типа `id` а не `BOOL` как указано в документации.  Как правильно с ним работать, чтобы получить его значение?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Синтаксис там максимально приближен к NSMutableDictionary, только помимо объектов там могут быть и примитивы типа `[pref boolForKey:@"MyKey"]` (pref - переменная, в которую вернули standartDefaults, можно и без нее в принципе, это все равно синглтон), какой конкретно у вас ключ не знаю. Единственное что - не забудьте дернуть synchronize до чтения\после записи новых значений

**UPD**

*"в таком варианте toggleSwitchValue типа id а не BOOL как указано в документации. Ккак правильно с ним работать чтобы получить его значение?"*

Что-то типа:

```
NSUserDefaults *defaults = [NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults];
NSNumber *toggleSwitchValue = [defaults objectForKey:@"PSToggleSwitchSpecifier"];
BOOL boolToggle=[toggleSwitchValue boolValue];
```

А вот можно ли было в этом бандле определить именно бул, не помню. Вручную точно можно, я как-то редко использую системные настройки

Comment: Попробую реализовать так, спасибо Вам за вариант!